# Update dependency repo during build start with fresh checkout strategy

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have build with additional dependency. For primary build sources I use fresh checkout strategy. But for dependency I need perform only update. Is it possible to run in single job? Now I have special job for updating dependency sources.

Comment: Is there any reason not to always work with update?

Comment: I have been strongly recommended to use this way by customer's main developer. It's like mandatory requirement for me. From my previous background I see some times when `update` is not work good enough. Also, clean checkout is something like best practice and I do not like not follow it.